# save changes despite DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I was trying to understand the optimistic concurrency in entity framework and I was unable to overwrite the changes with the latest one. Please take a look at the code.

```
var x = a.users.Where<users>(s => s.id == 4).First<users>();
x.name = "xxxx";
try{
      a.SaveChanges();
}
catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex){
     message("Overwrite other changes ? yes or no");
     if(yes){
         // overwrite the entity values with mine in the db
     }            
}
```

Basically when the record got updated by other user, Admin will look at the changes and he must overwrite the older values. How do I do that? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concurrency exception is for a particular transaction, if you want to have admin intervene in between, you need to a point where you can store transaction data, and then admin can decide which one to update.